# Problemas de instalacion SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, windows10

Estoy tratando de instalar SQL Server Express 2017 en una computadora, pero estoy recibiendo este error:

Error Unable to Install SQL Server (setup.exe)

Ya intente limpiar los registros de de instalación pero sigo recibiendo el mismo error, la arquitectura del equipo es Windows 10 PRO 64 BITS.

Aquí una imagen del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Log:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068052614
  Start time:                    2020-09-02 16:29:59
  End time:                      2020-09-02 16:30:31
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for SNAC:            Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for SNAC_SDK:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for ComponentUpdate: Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
```

ERRORES:

```
    Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Setup Support Files
  Component error code:          1402
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200902_162959\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Could not open key: UNKNOWN\Components\C0535529E259A3C4CB04810312C50A3B\CD2525047FDA8CB4595F8FD95E31DD26.   Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40InstallFiles%401402

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
  Component error code:          1402
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200902_162959\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Could not open key: UNKNOWN\Components\1C577CC61E2D0E84E920735D0B9EEA23\FF65C2D463F794B49AA7420F25D2147D.   Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40InstallFiles%401402

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
  Component error code:          1402
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200902_162959\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Could not open key: UNKNOWN\Components\1C577CC61E2D0E84E920735D0B9EEA23\FF65C2D463F794B49AA7420F25D2147D.   Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40InstallFiles%401402
```

Agradezco la ayuda que se me pueda dar para solucionar el problema.

Comment: ¿Qué dice el log de instalación? ¿Estás lanzando el instalador elevado?

Comment: Las primeras linas del Log muestran lo que agregue en la edicion de la pregunta.
A que te refieres con Instalador elevado?
Estoy haciendolo desde el ejecutable, lo he instalado en otros equipos y no habia tenido problemas.
@jachguate

Comment: Elevado me refiero a un usuario administrador y el proceso con privilegios elevados (botón derecho, run as admin, por ejemplo).

Comment: La parte del log que has puesto no dice nada... sugiero que busques información específica de los errores (cada uno) que han ocurrido durante la instalación. Ya que esos errores son los que van a explicar por qué no se ha logrado instalar.

Comment: Si asi es, asi lo estoy realizando
@jachguate

Comment: Los error hablan acerca de que no puede abrir una llave...
@jachguate

Comment: quizás esto te sea de ayuda: https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.100002346

Comment: O esto: https://help.act.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024414573-Error-Message-Error-1402-Could-not-open-key-UNKNOWN-Components-GUID-

Comment: Amigo, perdón que no lo ponga como respuesta, pero puede servir: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/02/14/sql-server-fix-error-1402-not-open-key-unknowncomponents-system-error-5/

Comment: Gracias a todos, he seguido los pasos de los hilos que me proponen y sigo sin poder realizar la instalación.
De hecho doy los permisos a mi usuario aplico cambio y voy a realizar la instalación me muestra el mismo error pero en otra SubCarpeta del la carpeta Components.
Alguna otra sugerencia?
@Alfabravo

Comment: @jachguate
Gracias a todos, he seguido los pasos de los hilos que me proponen y sigo sin poder realizar la instalación. De hecho doy los permisos a mi usuario aplico cambio y voy a realizar la instalación me muestra el mismo error pero en otra SubCarpeta del la carpeta Components. Alguna otra sugerencia?

Comment: El camino ancho es reinstalar el Windows. El camino angosto, podría simplificarse si de una vez le das permisos a todas las sub-carpetas de componentes.

Comment: @jachguate
Me creerías si te digo que ya lo hice y aun asi me marca el error.
El propietario que tenia era System para todas las carpetas lo cambie a mi usuario Full Access y como dueño y mismo error.
La PC donde quiero instalar es de la empresa por tal motivo tiene varios Software de seguridad pero me dieron tambien full access y hasta un nuevo usuario Administrador y sigo con el problema.
El reinstalar el Windows es una buena opción pero no quisiera llegar a eso.

Comment: Claro, te creo, estas cosas pasan. Si quieres ir por el camino angosto, puedes continuar viendo el error del log y corregirlos a medida que ocurren. Sería importante ver que no estés en un ciclo o en un punto muerto. Por ejemplo, verificar si no hay algo que esté, dentro del propio instalador, cambiando los permisos, o que se cree siempre una sub-carpeta nueva con los permisos equivocados... siempre que haya avance, puedes continuar por ese camino.

Comment: Gracias una disculpa por no contestar antes, pues como lo comentas, estoy dentro de un ciclo sin fin ya que doy los permisos y la Subcarpeta aparece en otra carpeta de la carpeta Components. Y asi una y otra vez me aparece el mismo error en diferente carpeta raiz.
Entonces tendré que ir por el camino corto reinstalar Windows.
Gracias por los aportes no dudo que estos funcionen pero en este caso algo mas esta ocurriendo.
Saludos
DS
@jachguate